# debugging a fastcgi application

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gdb, fastcgi

I have deployed a fastcgi application on my server. When I try to run it on the server, it crashes (more of this later).

First some facts on the local (dev) machine:

1. The application is C/C++ application
2. I developed the app on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS (same OS on server)
3. During development, I used gdb to step through code to fix initial bugs
4. I run ldd on the app and all required shared libs are found
5. I can test it on my local machine, using curl http://path/to/cgiapp

After getting the code tested and working on my local machine, I built a release version and packaged it, using Netbeans 6.9 IDE

I installed the package on the server and run the following tests

1. First run ldd on the installed app, I noticed that some files were not found. I fixed this by copying the files on the dev machine into the location that the app was searching for them (not ideal perhaps) - BUT, when I run ldd again, all libraries were found
2. I then tested the app by running curl http://path/to/cgiapp at the console

Instead of the expected message, there was what appeared to be a core dump (i.e. binary stream dump) onto the console.

My questions are:

1. Can anyone explain why ldd indicates all files (loaded?) correctly - and yet app crashes
2. What could be the most likely reason why the app runs on my dev machine but fails to run on the server?
3. Since the app crashes before starting, I am not sure how to use gdb to debug the application - obviously, I will copy the debug version to the server before I attempt to debug.

There are further complication regarding point 3 above. The server is a lean and mean, headless server, so it does not have gdb installed.

So even if I found a way to debug the app (before it crashes), I don't know how I can attach to a remote process.

Any ideas on how to start getting to the bottom of this would be much appreciated.

Comment: make sure the versions of the required `.so` files are the same on the two servers. copying .so files blindly from one machine to the other is _not_ the recommended way to keep a server in good operational state.

Comment: 1. You can copy your core dump to a machine with gdb and see a backtrace there. gdb -c core_name binary.name, then bt. 2. How do you know your app crashes before starting? Start logging things to a file instead of relying on live gdb sessions only.

Comment: @Torp: Thanks for your comment. I though I headed in the right direction - but after a little analysis, I realized that its actually the contents of the file itself that is being displayed on the console! (see edit)

Comment: @Torp: can you post your comment as an answer (so I can accept it). Although it wasn't the exact solution, it set me on the right path, and I was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Here ya go... reputation ftw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer at original poster's request:
1. You can copy your core dump to a machine with gdb and see a backtrace there. gdb -c core_name binary.name, then bt.
2. How do you know your app crashes before starting? Start logging things to a file instead of relying on live gdb sessions only.

Comment: For anyone interested ... I tried to run gdb -c from the "dump" (actually piped stream to a file), and gdb protested that it was not a dump file. I run 'file' on the dumped file and realized it was an executable. A little bit of investigation (using cmp etc), and I realized, what I initially thought was a core dump, was actually the contents of the file being streamed onto the console. the penny immediately dropped - I checked my Apache settings and realized that I had not yet set Apache up for fcgi - hence Apache was merely serving back the contents of the file as requested! SMH ...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on *way* too many misunderstandings.

> Can anyone explain why ldd indicates all files (loaded?) correctly - and yet app crashes

For the same reason some applications run 100s of times without any problems, then crash "randomly".

Not all crashes are related to the dynamic linker, in fact *majority* of crashes are not. Other bugs, such as heap corruption, buffer overflows, off-by-one errors, etc. etc. are much more frequent cause.

> What could be the most likely reason why the app runs on my dev machine but fails to run on the server?

You have not supplied sufficient data to answer that question.

What are the symptoms? Have you looked at apache error log for clues? What is the crash stack trace? Which libraries were missing on the server and were copied over?

> Since the app crashes before starting, I am not sure how to use gdb to debug the application - obviously, I will copy the debug version to the server before I attempt to debug.

You don't need to copy debug binary to debug it (it may or may not help, depending on where the crash actually happens).